# How can we give username/Designation wise access to app features?

Tags: android

I'm developing an CRM based android app but i want to add Username or salesperson wise app features like Complaint Management System(CMS) should be visible to only CMS-SALES person,All features like attendence and all should be visible to only admin.How can we do that?

Comment: You are asking for too much apparently whole Database structure  . Its way too broad to answer also an opinion based question. .

Comment: Just tell me the short procedure how to do it?Actually i'm new to app development so dont have idea about it

Comment: Start by adding a generic "role" field to your user objects (stored in your database). At runtime of app, use this information to enable/hide UI elements

Comment: Rather than focus on the specifics of what your app actually does, think abstractly like "how do you make some component only visible under certain conditions"